Fetching Data from flutter code(sqflite) for autofill service from Kotlin code when app is closed
I’m working on a Flutter password manager app and need help accessing data from an SQLite database (using sqflite) when the app is closed. The onRequestMethod of the AutofillService in Kotlin is called by android when app is closed if user is filling any form on app.  I’ve implemented the AutofillService in Kotlin but encountered issues with using the Flutter engine. Specifically, using the engine caused the app’s homepage to display and resulted in lag and performance delays.
I tried creating a new Activity and called it in onRequest override function.
I’m looking for a lighter solution to call a Dart function from Kotlin to retrieve data from the database. I would like to use method channels for this communication but need guidance on how to avoid showing the UI and ensure smooth performance.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
